# Discuss convergence and find sum of the Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1-\frac{{1}}{10^n})$ converges and find the sum
>   in closed form if it is possible.

Try:Clearly given series converges because if $0<a_n<1$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1-a_n)$ converges iff $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ converges. Give some hint for finding the sum of series.

Comment: Why do you suspect a closed form for the sum?

Comment: @Did you mean it is not possible to find in closed form?

Comment: I mean what I wrote (amazing, eh): why do you suspect a closed form for the sum, since you are asking (ordering, actually) for one?

Comment: @Did Actually I tried it for a long time but could not find any closed form so i was wondering whether is it possible or not?

Comment: Then why do you ask "find the sum"? This is misleading and, technically, makes your question not answerable.

Comment: @Did my mistake! Edited now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints for the convergence:

- For every $x$ in $(0,\frac1{10})$, $-2x\leqslant\log(1-x)\leqslant-x$.
- The series $\sum\limits_na^n$ converges absolutely for every $|a|\lt1$.

No reason to expect a closed form for the sum, an equivalent formula is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-1}{n(10^n-1)}.$$